# React Select Creatable "no options" instead of "create"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am trying to create a select element with react-select and I use the Creatable component for that.

With my current implementation, it won't prompt the user for "create" option on typing, as shown on the [documentation](https://react-select.com/creatable)
It will show instead the default "No options".

I am also using `redux-form` library but I don't think that the problem comes from there.

Here is my code so far :

```js
import Select from "react-select/creatable";
import React from "react";

const customFilter = (option, searchText) => {
  return option.data.searchfield.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
};

export default (props) => {
  const { input, options, placeholder } = props;

  const renderValue = (value) => {
    const val =
      value === "" ? null : options.find((obj) => obj.value === input.value);
    return val || "";
  };

  return (
    <Select
      value={renderValue(input.value)}
      name={input.name}
      onFocus={() => input.onFocus(input.value)}
      onChange={(value) => input.onChange(value.value)}
      onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
      options={options}
      isRtl={true}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      filterOption={customFilter}
    />
  );
};
```

**EDIT** :

I also tried from the docs to import the `makeCreatableSelect`  but it did not help:

```
    import Creatable, { makeCreatableSelect } from 'react-select/creatable';
<Creatable 
  //here goes props
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem here comes from your custom filter implementation

This a little bit tricky, because from the docs there is no example of the CreatableSelect with an implementation of custom filter.

To solve this, your custom filters must retrun `"undefined"` in order to "tell" to the `<CreatableSelect />` component that there is no such option.

So here is one option to achieve this :

```js
       const customFilter = (option, searchText) => {
          return option.data.searchfield !== undefined ? option.data.searchfield.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
: "undefined"
        };
```

In this way your CreatableSelect will known if the value was found

Another problem that I noticed in your code is that your `renderValue` method will return an empty string when it does not find a matching option...not good :  if you want the users to create option you have to render it when it will be created...not an empty string.

So replace this by something like :

```
    const renderValue = (value) => {
      const val = value === "" ? 
                  null : 
                  options.find((obj) => obj.value === input.value);
      return val || {value : value, label: value};
  };
```

That will create your new option. Of course you can change the label by your own logic.

Comment: I did not understand the second part of your answer, whats the problem with my rendervalue function ??

Comment: your `renderValue` method will only return values from the predefined options list. If it does not find it, it will return an empty string which is not what you want because you want to create the new option.

Comment: Yeah after some shots i understand that and now it works perfectly : thank you very much for your help !!